# Which is correct: "grammar rules" or "grammatical rules"?

Tags: grammar

> Which is one is correct English: "grammar rules" or "grammatical
>   rules" ?

In my opinion, "grammatical" means "conforming with the rules of grammar".

Thus, "grammatical rules" should literally mean "*rules which conform to the rules* of grammar". That is surely **not** the definition of "grammar rules".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I think you are correct! ***Grammar rules*** means rules about grammar. ***Grammatical rules*** are rules that are well-written and grammatical.

I think this means you can have ***grammatical grammar rules***. In fact, grammar rules should always be grammatical!

Answer (score 0):

I think "grammar rules" have to do with any rules in the language, for example in a third person singular, English rule says a morpheme "-s" is placed in the verb like "He speaks". Whereas "grammatical rules" have to do with the "logic" application of grammar rules in a logic form, for example, if a subject of a sentence is in a singular form the verb phrase must be singular.